# Use of SumIf function with range object or arrays

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm am trying to optimize a sub that uses Excel´s sumif function since it takes several time to finish.

The specific line (contained in to a for loop) is this one:

```
Cupones = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("Test_FecFinCup"), Arr_FecFlujos(i), Range("Test_MtoCup"))
```

Where the ranges are named ranges in the workbook, and Arr_FecFlujos() is an array of dates

That, code works fine, except for it takes to much time to finish.

I am trying this two approaches
Arrays:

Declare my arrays

```
With Test
  Fluj = .Range(Range("Test_Emision").Cells(2, 1), Range("Test_Emision").Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
  Arr_FecFinCup = .Range("Test_FecFinCup")
  Arr_MtoCup = .Range("Test_MtoCup")
End With

Cupones = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Arr_FecFinCup, Arr_FecFlujos(i), Arr_MtoCup)
```

Error tells me I need to work with Range Objects, so I changed to:

```
With Test
 Set Rango1 = .Range("Test_FecIniCup")
 Set Rango2 = .Range("Test_MtoCup")
End With

Cupones = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Rango1, Arr_FecFlujos(i), Rango2)
```

That one, doesn't shows any error messages, but the sum is incorrect.

Can anybody tell me what's working wrong with these methods and perhaps point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Have you tried `sumifs`?

Comment: Not yet, does it works in a different way tan SumIf

Comment: The code which is producing the incorrect sum is using slightly differently named ranges. The original code has `Range("Test_FecFinCup")` as the first range whereas the incorrect code uses `Set Rango1 = .Range("Test_FecIniCup")` Is this intentional?

Comment: Can´t believe I let it pass, I feel so dumb.  Thank you very much barrowc thats were I was wrong.  And thanks also to all that who took time to read this post.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you try to sum a range of numbers using a range of criteria:

```
WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Arr_FecFinCup, Arr_FecFlujos(i), Arr_MtoCup)
```

As i know, if the criteria parameter is given a range, Excel don't iterate over that range but instead look for the one value in the criteria_range that coincides with the row of the cell that it is calculating.

For example

```
Range("D3") = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("A1:A10"),Range("B1:B10"))
```

Excel will actually calculate as follow

```
Range("D3") = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("A1:A10"),Range("B3"))
```

If there is no coincident, then the return is 0

For example

```
Range("D7") = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("A1:A10"),Range("B1:B5"))
```

Then D7 is always 0 because looking for [B7] in [B1:B5] is out of range.

Therefore, to do a sum with multiple criterias, the correct way is using SUMIFS as suggested by @mrtiq.